# How to filter SharePoint list column with username of the current user

Tags: list, filter, conditional

I need to pass the **current user name** in the filter for **Contains** condition - Whenever passing [Me] it gives error: Filter value is not a valid text string.

[image]

Comment: Is the PoC field a people picker?

Comment: @wjervis No, it is Single line of text auto generated from the Infopath field.

Answer (score 2):

The List View filter value for the people or group field it takes [Me]. It works for Created By in your screenshot. If the PoC field is a text field there is no way you can pass the current user name.

You need to add a "Current User Filter" web part along with list view web part and connect both web parts.

- Go to page where you have list view web part added.
- Add "Current User Filter" web part under "Filters" section in the web parts gallery to the same page.
- Click down arrow on web part and click "connection" and select your list.
- And configure the connection.

Below MSDN article explains the complete steps
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Filter-Web-Part-to-a-Data-View-Web-Part-bc10362e-afaa-42dc-b09e-ba8b1b83bb3c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bms4

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that out of the box, but it would be rather easy to write a javascript to take the logged in user from the _spPageContextInfo object and use that as a filter. But if you want non-code solution the answer from VenKat is better.